# iPhone to Arduino over Sparkfun's bluetooth mate silver

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to replicate this sketch because I though it looked simple to replicate:

[instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Iphone-bluetooth-control-arduino/)

I am using a Sparkfun Bluetooth Mate Silver instead of the bluetooth antenna in the instructable.  However, I cannot seem to connect to, or even see, my antenna when I open that app.  I can connect to my iPhone through the Arduino serial port command line following these instructions:

[sparkfun tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/using-the-bluesmirf/all)

but that does not seem to help me do anything from the iPhone side.  I am pretty new to bluetooth so I am sure I am missing something so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS does not support the Serial Port Protocol (SPP) Profile (see [supported profiles](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387)), but the Sparkfun Bluetooth Mate Silver uses it as default. There are some models of the [Bluetooth Mate Silver module with HID firmware](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10938) that should work as an HID device with iOS. But I would recommend you to use a microcontroller with a integrated BLE chip, such as the [RFduino](http://www.rfduino.com/) or the chips from [RedBearLab](http://redbearlab.com/) that work fine with iOS via bluetooth. Otherwise you can buy a BLE bluetooth chip and use any compatible Arduino controller.

Comment: drat, wish i would have known that before buying.  thanks, for your help.